# implementing type inference

Tags: compiler-construction, functional-programming, language-design, type-inference

I see some interesting discussions here about static vs. dynamic typing.
I generally prefer static typing, due to compile type checking, better documented code, etc. However, I do agree that they do clutter up the code if done the way Java does it, for example.

So I'm about to start building a functional style language of my own, and type inference is one of the things that I want to implement. I do understand that it is a big subject, and I'm not trying to create something that has not been done before, just basic inferencing...

Any pointers on what to read up that will help me with this? Preferably something more pragmatic/practical as opposed to more theoretical category theory/type theory texts. If there's an implementation discussion text out there, with data structures/algorithms, that would just be lovely.

Comment: Exactly the question I was looking for, with some great answers!

Answer (score 99):

I found the following resources helpful for understanding type inference, in order of increasing difficulty:

1. Chapter 30 (Type Inference) of [the freely available book PLAI](http://www.plai.org), *Programming Languages: Application and Interpretation*, sketches unification-based type inference.
2. The summer course [*Interpreting types as abstract values*](http://okmij.org/ftp/Computation/Computation.html#teval) presents elegant evaluators, type checkers, type reconstructors and inferencers using Haskell as a metalanguage.
3. Chapter 7 (Types) of [the book EOPL](http://www.eopl3.com/), *Essentials of Programming Languages*.
4. Chapter 22 (Type Reconstruction) of [the book TAPL](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/), *Types and Programming Languages*, and the corresponding OCaml implementations [recon](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/checkers/recon/core.ml) and [fullrecon](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/checkers/fullrecon/core.ml).
5. Chapter 13 (Type Reconstruction) of [the new book DCPL](http://dcpl.mit.edu/), *Design Concepts in Programming Languages*.
6. [Selection of academic papers](https://pinboard.in/u:namin/t:type-inference+paper).
7. Closure compiler's [TypeInference](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#l5BkQmivP-Y/trunk/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/TypeInference.java&q=TypeInference%20package:http://closure-compiler%5C.googlecode%5C.com&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc) is an example of the data-flow analysis approach to type inference, which is better suited to dynamic languages that the Hindler Milner approach.

However, since the best way to learn is to do, I strongly suggest implementing type inference for a toy functional language by working through a homework assignment of a programming languages course.

I recommend these two accessible homeworks in ML, which you can both complete in less than a day:

1. [PCF Interpreter](http://users.cs.fiu.edu/~smithg/cop4555/hw5.html) ([a solution](http://github.com/namin/spots/tree/master/pcf/interp1.sml)) to warm up.
2. [PCF Type Inference](http://users.cs.fiu.edu/~smithg/cop4555/hw6.html) ([a solution](http://github.com/namin/spots/tree/master/pcf/type.sml)) to implement algorithm W for Hindley-Milner type inference.

[These assignments](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/15312-f04/assignments.html) are from a more advanced course:

1. [Implementing MiniML](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/15312-f04/assignments/asst2/index.html)
2. [Polymorphic, Existential, Recursive Types (PDF)](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/15312-f04/assignments/asst5.pdf)
3. [Bi-Directional Typechecking (PDF)](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/15312-f04/assignments/asst6/index.html)
4. [Subtyping and Objects (PDF)](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/15312-f04/assignments/asst7.pdf)

Comment: Is it just me, or is the PLAI description largely incorrect/incomplete? [The lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sbhpJvAevz0) adds a bit more to it, but still seemingly not enough to get it to work.

Comment: I also couldn't get the algorithm in the 2012 version of the PLAI book. There are no substitutions to the constraint list. Instead, I implemented the type inference algorithm in the 2003-7 version of the PLAI book, it seems to work better, and scale well to let-polymorphism as well.

Comment: It seems that the recon and fullrecon links are broken. The gziped versions are still available: [recon.tar.gz](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/checkers/recon.tar.gz), [fullrecon.tar.gz](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/checkers/fullrecon.tar.gz).

Comment: Do we have any examples of how to implement typechecking / type inference from an imperative language perspective, instead of functional language perspective?

Answer (score 32):

It's unfortunate that much of the literature on the subject is very dense. I too was in your shoes. I got my first introduction to the subject from Programming Languages: Applications and Interpretation

http://www.plai.org/

I'll try to summarize the abstract idea followed by details that I did not find immediately obvious. First, type inference can be thought of generating and then solving constraints. To generate constraints, you recurse through the syntax tree and generate one or more constraints on each node. For example, if the node is a `+` operator, the operands and the results must all be numbers. A node that applies a function has the same type as the result of the function, and so on.

For a language without `let`, you can blindly solve the above constraints by substitution. For example:

```
(if (= 1 2) 
    1 
    2)
```

here, we can say that the condition of the if statement must be Boolean, and that the type of the if statement is the same as the type of its `then` and `else` clauses. Since we know `1` and `2` are numbers, by substitution, we know the `if` statement is a number.

Where things get nasty, and what I couldn't understand for a while, is dealing with let:

```
(let ((id (lambda (x) x)))
    (id id))
```

Here, we've bound `id` to a function that returns whatever you've passed in, otherwise known as the identity function. The problem is the type of the function's parameter `x` is different on each usage of `id`. The second `id` is a function of type `a -> a`, where `a` can be anything. The first is of type `(a -> a) -> (a -> a)`. This is known as let-polymorphism. The key is to solve constraints in a particular order: first solve constraints for the definition of `id`. This will be `a -> a`. Then fresh, separate copies of the type of `id` can be substituted into the constraints for each place `id` is used, for example `a2 -> a2` and `a3 -> a3`.

That wasn't readily explained in online resources. They'll mention algorithm W or M but not how they work in terms of solving constraints, or why it doesn't barf on let-polymorphism: each of those algorithms enforce an ordering on solving the constraints.

I found this resource extremely helpful to tie Algorithm W, M, and the general concept of constraint generation and solving all together. It's a little dense, but better than many:

http://www.cs.uu.nl/research/techreps/repo/CS-2002/2002-031.pdf

Many of the other papers there are nice too:

http://people.cs.uu.nl/bastiaan/papers.html

I hope that helps clarify a somewhat murky world.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to Hindley Milner for functional languages, another
popular approach to type inference for dynamic language is
`abstract interpretation`.

The idea of abstract interpretation is to write a special
interpreter for the language, instead of keep an environment of
concrete values(1, false, closure), it works on abstract values, aka
types(int, bool, etc). Since it's interpreting the program on
abstract values, that's why it's called abstract interpretation.

Pysonar2 is an elegant implementation of abstract interpretation
for Python. It is used by Google to analyze Python
projects. Basically it uses `visitor pattern` to dispatch
evaluation call to relevant AST node. The visitor function [`transform`](http://www.codatlas.com/project/_I_Xhzhsm_vE9TA1gGu-zQ__/HEAD/src/main/java/org/yinwang/pysonar/ast/Node.java?line=123)
accepts the [`context`](http://www.codatlas.com/project/_I_Xhzhsm_vE9TA1gGu-zQ__/HEAD/src/main/java/org/yinwang/pysonar/State.java?line=14) in which current node will be evaluated, and
returns the type of current node.

Answer (score 5):

Types and Programming Languages by Benjamin C. Pierce

Answer (score 4):

Lambda the Ultimate, starting [here](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/492).