# How does Haskell know which typeclass instance you mean?

Tags: haskell, type-inference, typeclass

This question arose while reading the new chapter in the excellent Learn You a Haskell about applicative functors.

The Applicative typeclass has, as part of the definition for the Maybe instance:

```
pure = Just
```

If I just go to GHCi and import Control.Applicative, and do:

```
pure (3+)
```

I don't get Just anything (makes sense). But if I use it in part of the expression:

```
pure (3+) <*> Just 4
```

I get Just 7. I guess it also isn't surprising, but I'm missing something integral about how typeclasses work, I think, that there is no ambiguity with the call to `pure` here.

If my confusion makes sense, can anyone explain what's going on in detail?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just type inference. The `(<*>)` operator requires both arguments to use the same `Applicative` instance. The right side is a `Maybe`, so the left side has to be a `Maybe` also. So that's how it figures out which instance is used here. You can look at the type of any expression in the interpreter by typing `:t expression`, and maybe if you just go through each subexpression and look at the type that was inferred, you will get a better picture of what's going on.

Comment: Ah, so does the compiler do something like "Hmm, this argument's type is ambiguous, so let me check the next argument's type and come back to it"?

Comment: Type inference is quite complex, but it's worth knowing that it doesn't happen in one step. The type inferencer usually collects some information in one step, and at a later stage some more information. So it doesn't just infer the correct types for everything in one go, from left to right. In this case, it will infer that `pure` is of type `(Applicative a1) => a1 (Int -> Int)` where the `a1` is just a made up type variable, at a later stage during type inference it will conclude that `a1` must be `Maybe`, and then it will substitute `Maybe` for `a1` everywhere.

Comment: Thank you -- that is quite helpful!

Answer (score 3):

It's worth looking at the type the compiler infers for `pure (3+)`:

```
Prelude Control.Applicative> :t pure (3+)
pure (3+) :: (Num a, Applicative f) => f (a -> a)
```

The type of this term is overloaded, and the decision about the numeric class and the applicative class is delayed until later.  But you can force a particular type with an annotation, for example:

```
*Showfun Control.Applicative> pure (3+) :: Maybe (Double -> Double)
Just <function>
```

(This works because `Showfun` has an instance declaration that prints a function value as `<function>`.)

It's just a question of when the compiler has accumulated enough information to make a decision.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the `Showfun` module in some existing package, or is is just something you wrote yourself? The implementation is straightforward enough: `instance Show (a -> b) where;  show _ = "<function>"`

Comment: I wrote Showfun myself so I could get the example `pure (3+)` to print using `Just`.

Comment: ShowFunctions is in QuickCheck now, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

To expand a bit on newacct's answer, if there isn't enough information to infer the actual type, the compiler may (in some cases) attempt to select a default type, limited to those that would satisfy the type constraints in question. In this case, the type inferred is IO (n -> n) for some difficult-to-determine instance of Num => n. GHCi then evaluates it and throws away the return value, with no visible effect.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interesting [SO thread on type inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415532/implementing-type-inference).  Not Haskell specific, but lots of good links and stuff to read about type inference in functional languages.