# Static code analysis in Python?

Tags: python, debugging, refactoring, static-code-analysis

Which helpful static code analysis can you recommend for Python. I believe they are useful for refactoring code.
I know

- snakefood for module dependencies
- pycallgraph for dynamic call graphs
- pylint for bugs

Are there static call analyzers? If I wanted to program a custom one, which would be the easiest way?

What other type of static code checks can you think of? Or maybe even some Python magic like ABCs?

EDIT: I've found that either using http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/ast.html or maybe even http://www.astroid.org/ can be used to program some custom parser. Then one can use graphviz to visualize or even PlantUML for UML graphs.

Comment: This seems to be about 5 different questions. You may want to split it up.

Comment: unittests are useful for refactoring code too.

Answer (score 2):

check out [pychecker](http://pychecker.sourceforge.net/) and [pyflakes](https://launchpad.net/pyflakes). There was a famous question to discuss the [pylint-pychecker-or-pyflakes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428872/pylint-pychecker-or-pyflakes)

Answer (score 2):

this is a very powerful python type inferencer
https://github.com/yinwang0/pysonar2

it has strong bug check ability but it's not exposed through its interface, but I assume you could do many awesome checks based on it.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly "static code analyzer" but even a bit more:

http://code.google.com/p/shedskin/

Answer (score 0):

Pysonar2 is a very nice implementation of `abstract interpretation` to type inference Python projects. My answer to another similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27978019/3261577).