# Automatically generate data for unit testing in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, numpy, metaprogramming, metaclass

I have a module to test, module includes a serie of functions / simple classes.
Wondering if there any attempts(ie package) to generate automatically:

1) Generate Python code from initial Python file containing function definition.

2) This code list of call to the functions with random/parametric data as parameters.

It is technically feasible by using inspect and python meta classes,
usually limited to numerical type functions....(numpy array).

Because string (ie url input) would be impossible (only parametrized...).

EDIT: By random, it means obviously "parametric random".

Suppose we have

```
  def f(x1,x2,x3) 

  For all xi of f
   if type(xi) = array1D -> 
       Do those tests: empty array, zeros array, negative array(random),   
      positivearray(random), high values, low values, integer array, real  
      number array, ordered array, equal space array,..... 

   if type(xi)=int -> test  zero, 1, 2,3,4, randomValues, Negative
```

Do people think such project is possible using inspect and meta class? (limited to numpy/numerical items).

Suppose you have a very large library..., things can be done in background.

Comment: Is that really direction you want to go with testing - building the tests from the functions?  In test-driven development, you create the tests, and design the functions to work correctly in those tests.  Random data doesn't do a good job of rooting out problems.  Problems usually occur in the edge cases - empty arrays, 0 values, nan values, unexpected values.

Comment: Hi, By random, it means obviously "parametric random". Let's take an example func(x1,x2,x3)   ,  if type(xi) = array1D  -> Do those tests:  empty array, zeros array, negative array(random), positivearray(random), high values, low values, integer array, real number array,.....

Answer (score 1):

You might be thinking of fuzz testing, where a bunch of garbage data is submitted to a function to see if anything makes it behave badly. It sounds like [the Hypothesis library](https://github.com/DRMacIver/hypothesis) will let you generate different test cases based on some parameters.

Comment: Hypothesis looks closer to the question. 2 items are missing : 1) This is not garbage data: this is parametrized data, data follows some boundaries.    2) Result of the output : crash, error, result....  can be analyzed to guess what the function is doing  3)behave badly is only a side effect/consequence....

Comment: Just with Hypothese people, Hypothese, you need to find and put an invariant of the function. Everything is checked againts this invariant.

Answer (score 0):

I spent searching, it seems this kind of project does not really exist (to my knowledge):

Technically, this is a mix of packages (issues):

Hypothese : data generation for input, running the code with crash/error.
  (without the invariant part of Hypothese)

Jedi: Static analysis of code/Inference of the type
  Type inference is a difficult issue in  Python (in general)
[implementing type inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415532/implementing-type-inference)

If type is num/array of num:
 Boundary exists/ typical usage is clearly defined

If type is string: Inference is pretty difficult without human guessing.

Same for others, Context guessing is important